# Reopen a file closed by vim quickfix

Tags: vim

When I use vim's quickfix to jump to errors in my build, if the file containing an error isn't already open it opens it in one of my splits, replacing the file I had open.

Is there a way to either reopen last closed file in a split or get quickfix to open files in a new split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the quickfix window open then pressing `<ctrl-W><enter>` while the cursor is on the error you want to go to will open the file in a new split window.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do... though I think Zyx's answer also solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try using `<C-o>` in normal mode. It takes you to the previous position, even if previous position was in other file.

Comment: This (and what Dave Kirby said) is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: OP: This is a generally useful keystroke that is complemented by `<C-i>`, which goes forward through the files that `<C-o>` went backward through.

Answer (score 2):

what I do in this case is the following: before starting the compilation
process I first split the window

```
:sp
```

After the compilation process I just go to the original window (the one I created with split) and do CTRL-w+o closing other windows and leaving me in the original position.

Comment: You can also split and run a command all in one go, e.g.  `:sp make`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:cn` `:cp` `:cl` to jump to previous/next/list errors in a build. This way you can :bn and then :bp. Or use markers: `ma`, `'a`.

Comment: Oups *Mea Coupa*. It's `cn`, `cp`, `cl`. HA HA Very sorry.